# upgrading commons-httpclient-3.1.jar to httpclient-4.5.2.jar

Tags: java, axis, apache-commons-httpclient

Well due to some vulnerability we need to move from commons-httpclient-3.1.jar to httpclient-4.5.2.jar

Now  have a code base which was working before on 3.1, but the methods are depreceted in 4.5.2. Do you have any idea or came across on how to overcome these errors

Error I get is 
1) The import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HostConfiguration cannot be resolved
2) The method getState() is undefined for the type HttpClient

Here is the source code. Let me know if you have any information.

```
import org.apache.axis.MessageContext;

import org.apache.axis.components.net.TransportClientProperties;
import org.apache.axis.components.net.TransportClientPropertiesFactory;
import org.apache.http.auth.Credentials;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HostConfiguration;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import java.net.URL;


public class CommonsHTTPSender extends
        org.apache.axis.transport.http.CommonsHTTPSender {

    public static final String PROPERTY_PROXY_HOST = "https.proxyHost";
    public static final String PROPERTY_PROXY_PORT = "https.proxyPort";
    public static final String PROPERTY_PROXY_USERNAME = "https.proxyUser";
    public static final String PROPERTY_PROXY_PASSWORD = "https.proxyPassword";

    public CommonsHTTPSender() {
    }

    protected HostConfiguration getHostConfiguration(HttpClient client,
            MessageContext context, URL targetURL) {

        HostConfiguration config = new HostConfiguration();
        if ( targetURL.getProtocol().equalsIgnoreCase("https") )
        {
            //Jli: our changes start from here. There is a defect in the DefaultHTTPSTransportClientProperties.
            // The class is only called once to get the proxy setttings from the system properties. If users
            // Change the proxy settings, the class will not pick up the changes. On our DMDI GUI, users
            // can make the changes as often as they can. This will create an issue that when the apache axis
            // reconnect, it only picks up the proxy setup that users put in the GUI the first time.
            // We only use the HTTPS, so this change is only valid for the https.  

            int urlPort = targetURL.getPort();
            if (urlPort == -1) {
                urlPort = 443; // default port for https being 443
            }
            String proxyHost = (String)System.getProperty(PROPERTY_PROXY_HOST);
            String proxyPort = (String)System.getProperty(PROPERTY_PROXY_PORT);
            String proxyUsername = (String)System.getProperty(PROPERTY_PROXY_USERNAME);
            String proxyPassword = (String)System.getProperty(PROPERTY_PROXY_PASSWORD);

            if ( proxyHost == null || proxyPort == null ||
                    proxyHost.length() == 0  || proxyPort.length() == 0) {
                  config.setHost(targetURL.getHost(), urlPort, targetURL
                          .getProtocol());
            } else {
                 if ( proxyUsername != null &&  proxyPassword != null && proxyUsername.length() != 0) {
                    Credentials proxyCred = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxyUsername,
                            proxyPassword);
                    // if the username is in the form "user\domain"
                    // then use NTCredentials instead.
                    int domainIndex = proxyUsername.indexOf("\\");
                    if (domainIndex > 0) {
                        String domain = proxyUsername.substring(0,
                                domainIndex);
                        if (proxyUsername.length() > domainIndex + 1) {
                            String user = proxyUsername.substring(
                                    domainIndex + 1);
                            proxyCred = new NTCredentials(user, proxyPassword, proxyHost,
                                    domain);
                        }
                    }
                    client.getState().setProxyCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
                            proxyCred);



                }
                int proxyPortInt = new Integer(proxyPort).intValue();
                config.setProxy(proxyHost, proxyPortInt);
            }     
        }
        else
        {
            config = super.getHostConfiguration(client, context, targetURL);
        }
        return config;
    }

}
```

Comment: The 3.x and 4.x versions are not compatible. The architecture is completely changed. You need to rewrite the code that uses it.